# Setting text for IXMDOMNodePtr

Tags: string, c++11, mfc, com, msxml6

I have a MFC application for which Character set is "Not set".

I am using MSXML to create a XML.

When I try the following, the code crashes -

```
std::string lText ("abc");
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pAttr = GetAttr(); //pNode is initialized fine
pNode->text = (_bstr_t)lText.c_string();
```

Surprisingly, this code was working fine till Visual studio 2008.
Now I am using Visual studio 2013, and it crashes.

I am using the following way to make my code work.

```
    variant.vt = VT_BSTR;
    variant.bstrVal = bValue;
    pAttr->put_nodeValue(variant);
```

This works but I do not know what really went wrong. Please help??

Comment: Did you try `std::wstring` instead? Hasn't your code been converted to Unicode?

Comment: I cannot use wstring without changing the character set to Unicode. Not allowed in my current project infrastructure.

Comment: What is the line crashing? What feedback do you receive?

Comment: Setting the text to node crashes. It is a _com_error

Comment: What _com_error? Also pAttr->put_nodeValue is something different to pNode->text. You didn't show us what pNode is!